# C++ Program in Docker container

Tags: c++, docker

I am using following function inside container to execute command line argument `cd /mypath && sha1sum -c mysha1sumfile` to compare the sha1sum of files available in /mypath with the values in mysha1sumfile in the same path. The command is working in when I execute it as binary. The same is working when I tried manually inside the container by executing /bin/bash (inside container). But not working from the program.

```
executeCmd(const char* command)
{
  string response = "";
  char buffer[256];   
  FILE* pipe = popen(command,"r");  

  if(!pipe)  {  
    response = "ERROR";  
  }  
  while(!feof(pipe)){        
    if(fgets(buffer,128,pipe) != NULL){
      response += buffer;
    }  
  }  
  pclose(pipe);  
  return response;  
}
```

Verified that `pipe` is not `NULL` and `feof(pipe)` is also not `NULL`. But `fgets()` returning `NULL`.

What can cause that?

Comment: Some causes why `std::fgets()` might fail, and returns a `NULL` pointer, are listed [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fgets).

Comment: I don't know the reason but your code shows the common misunderstanding that `feof` tells you whether your file position is at the 'end of file'. It doesn't, instead it tells you whether the end of file flag is set. The end of file flag is only set when a **previous** operation failed because of end of file. There is no point calling `feof` before a `fgets` to try and anticipate an end of file error. In short I would guess that `fgets` fails because you hit the end of file, despite your attempts to avoid this..

Comment: Thank's for your comment. I could resolve the issue. It was due to a missing library libtinfo.so.5 for shell scrip ("sh") inside the container. After the library has been copied to /lib/ inside the container it started working.

Answer (score 0):

Thank's for your comment. I could resolve the issue. It was due to a missing library libtinfo.so.5 for shell scrip ("sh") inside the container. After the library has been copied to /lib/ inside the container it started working

Comment: How did you find this out?  What changes did you have to make to your Dockerfile to address it?